# Directed graphs in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a graph that I am creating rules on. [owes money graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqqh4.gif)
I have created rules that shows who owes money to who

```
owes(alice,5,charlie).
owes(alice,20,bob).
owes(bob,10,charlie).
```

I have created rules that display who owes someone under a certain amount or over

```
owesOver10(X,Y) :-owes(X,Y,Z),(Y>=10).
owesUnder10(X,Y) :-owes(X,Y,Z),(Y<10).
```

however know I need to write a rule that shows how much money a person owes in total so for instance it should display 25 for `alice`, and 10 for `bob`.

Answer (score 1):

I propose the use of `findall/3` to get a list of all owes and a simple `sumList/2` to get the sum of the values.

By example

```
listSum([], 0).
listSum([H | T], S0) :-
  listSum(T, S1),
  S0 is S1 + H.

totOwes(X, S) :-
  findall(Y, owes(X, Y, _), L),
  listSum(L, S).
```

Calling `totOwes(alice, S)`, I get that `S` is unified with `25`; for `bob` with `10` and for `charlie` with `0`.